# d3 binding data to a group does not seem to propagate after creation

Tags: d3.js

My understanding was that binding data on a group had the effect of propagating the data to all the elements in the group

What I notice is that when I bind data to a group, all the elements that I **append** in the group also get the data. However, if I update the data and re-bind to the group, the new data do not propagate to the elements in the group.

For example, when changing dataLegend and doing this

```
var g = legend.selectAll("g")
  .data(dataLegend);

g.selectAll("text")
.text(function(d) { 
return d.term; })
```

the text element does not seem to change its value.

Can anybody give me any comments to see whether this makes sense or not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The operations that propagate bound data in D3 are `.append()`, `.insert()`, and `.select()`. `.selectAll()` does *not* propagate data. If you have just a single `text` element underneath each `g` element, you can use `.select()`, which will also update the bound data. Otherwise, you'll have to bind the updated data yourself.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the very clear answer! While this answers my question perfectly, I wonder why select propagates, but selectAll does not.

Comment: It's simply an implementation decision. I guess the case where you have multiple elements below one that they should all inherit the same data from doesn't arise that often.